# Standard Dialogtitles in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Is there a way to determine windows titles in Windows. When automating the printing I want to find the save file dialog. The problem is the title differs between the locales.

- For de-DE

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(0, "Druckausgabe speichern unter");
```

- For en-EN

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(0, "Save Print output as");
```

Is there a way to determine these Standard window titles?

Comment: There is no API that provides this information. Though the problem you are trying to solve probably has a solution. Maybe you should ask about the problem rather than your proposed solution based on `FindWindow`.

Comment: Well, for printers, there should be a way to accumulate the names of each printer and display your own dialog that you can control.

Comment: Many standard dialogs provide an option to let the program customize the dialog's title, so there is really no standard solution for this.

Comment: why do you want the save file dialog just for automatic printing? This is probably an [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/230282)

Comment: The tool will be used for test automation. So there is no control over the printing what so ever. So the given is the standard "print to pdf" workflow and need to know the dialog titles.

Comment: You don't need to know the window title ahead of time when using [WinEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/winevents-infrastructure).

Answer (score 0):

To access the titles [MUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/mui-application-specific-settings-sample-vista) can be used. All the strings are externalized and will be supplied in the user language.

```
wchar_t printDlgTitle[1024];
HMODULE h = LoadLibraryEx(L"comdlg32.dll", NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE); 
// the dll I know the associated .mui has the id
LoadString(h, 1124, printDlgTitle, ARRAYSIZE(printDlgTitle));
FreeLibrary(h);
```

1124 is the number of the string in the string table.

[ResoruceHacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) can be used to obtain the ids. In this instance open comdlg32.dll.mui of your language.